# Addressbook linker error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

When I use `__bridge_transfer` or `__bridge`:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
{
    NSString* nameFirst = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                   kABPersonFirstNameProperty);       
    NSString* nameLast = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    _sight.contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", nameFirst, nameLast];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

Code above produces an error below:

```
Ld /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Guides-bgsawzdhvfxryifctnadtvdzotfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Guides.app/Guides normal i386
    cd "/Users/atencion/Documents/Applications Development/Xcode Projects/Guides"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Guides-bgsawzdhvfxryifctnadtvdzotfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Guides-bgsawzdhvfxryifctnadtvdzotfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Guides-bgsawzdhvfxryifctnadtvdzotfx/Build/Intermediates/My Guides.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Guides.build/Objects-normal/i386/Guides.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework AddressBookUI -framework MessageUI -framework Twitter -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreImage -framework MapKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Guides-bgsawzdhvfxryifctnadtvdzotfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Guides.app/Guides

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
      -[ContactInfoViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in ContactInfoViewController.o
  "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
      -[ContactInfoViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in ContactInfoViewController.o
  "_kABPersonLastNameProperty", referenced from:
      -[ContactInfoViewController peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:] in ContactInfoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Addressbook and AddressbookUI frameworks added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem was that Addressbook framework was in my project, but dissappeared from "Project"-"Summary tab"-"Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

After I added framework there all problems gone.