# Issues in using address book framework of IOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

I am trying to use address framework in my project. I have linked the frameworks AddressBookUI.framework and AddressBook.framework in my project. But still i am getting the below error while building the app.

Help me to figure out the issue please.

```
Ld "/Users/sathishkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy_Contacts-eafemguogncacmhgnbfsjtizjcbd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Easy Contacts.app/Easy Contacts" normal i386
    cd "/Users/sathishkumar/projects/Easy Contacts"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/sathishkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy_Contacts-eafemguogncacmhgnbfsjtizjcbd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/sathishkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy_Contacts-eafemguogncacmhgnbfsjtizjcbd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/sathishkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy_Contacts-eafemguogncacmhgnbfsjtizjcbd/Build/Intermediates/Easy Contacts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Easy Contacts.build/Objects-normal/i386/Easy Contacts.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/sathishkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy_Contacts-eafemguogncacmhgnbfsjtizjcbd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Easy Contacts.app/Easy Contacts"

    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
          -[ViewController displayPerson:] in ViewController.o
      "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced from:
          -[ViewController displayPerson:] in ViewController.o
      "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
          -[ViewController displayPerson:] in ViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPeoplePickerNavigationController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
          -[ViewController displayPerson:] in ViewController.o
      "_kABPersonPhoneProperty", referenced from:
          -[ViewController displayPerson:] in ViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<AddressBook/AddressBook.h>` to the file, AddressBookUI is just that address book UI.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536591/addressbook-linker-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386)

Comment: well it worked after i linked the frameworks again with the above piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

Did you import those frameworks into your .h files?

Comment: did you `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`?